# Is a scollable TextSelectionMenu possible?

Tags: android

It seems impossible to find any answer on my question/problem regarding af scollable TextSelectionMenu! I have searched the whole Stackoverflow and Google without any succes and I have tried various ideas out.

I have 10 menu items in my custom TextSelectionMenu. Only 6 of them is visible, the rest is of course not, since you can't scroll to the others. Is it possible to implement a Scrollview/HorizontalListview of any sort to be able to scroll to the rest?

[image]

**My menu_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/textcolor"
        android:icon="@drawable/textcolor"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="ColorPicker"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bold"
        android:icon="@drawable/bold2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="Bold"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

   <item
        android:visible="true"
        android:id="@+id/italic"
        android:icon="@drawable/italic2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Italic"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

   <item
        android:visible="true"
        android:id="@+id/underline"
        android:icon="@drawable/underline2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Underline"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:visible="true"
        android:id="@+id/stroke"
        android:icon="@drawable/strike"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Strikethrough"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:visible="true"
        android:id="@+id/increase"
        android:icon="@drawable/increase"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Increase"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:visible="true"
        android:id="@+id/decrease"
        android:icon="@drawable/decrease"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Decrease"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
```

**The CustomTextSelectionMenu class:**

```
public class CustomTextSelectionMenu extends FragmentActivity implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.paste);
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Just a lot of switch cases inside here... 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding customView(scroll view) in the action/tool bar?

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi I just updated the screenshot, the other may be a little bit misleading. But I tried it. It ended up very messy!

Comment: What do you mean by "Messy",  I think it is doable with horizontal scrollView/RecyclerView or any custom view which allows you to slide left/right. Try more in this part, you will have to make it look by UI tweaking.

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi I will try the next few days post the result of it

Comment: Sure, Comment here and I will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no way to scroll the text selection menu.
But you can do is, `show the few menu items say 2 or 3` as `showAsAction="always"` and the rest of the menu items are automatically can be shown in `overflow menu`.

Comment: Yeah that solution will be used if everything else is not possible!
Its so frustrating! Any way to contact google about it?

Comment: Just updated the screenshot for a better understanding